# Writing a function that returns a base and an exponent

Tags: c++

I recently bought the C++ How to Program, Early Objects Version 9th edition to better verse myself in C++ programming. I am on chapter 6 of the book and I am in the questions section and I am having trouble with this question.

Write a single function `integerPower(base, exponent)` that returns the value of `base ^ exponent`

For example, `integerPower(3, 4) = 3 * 3 * 3 * 3`. Assume that exponent is a positive, nonzero, integer, and that base is an integer. **DO NOT USE ANY MATH LIBRARY FUNCTIONS**

I felt the need to put that in all caps and bold because they don't want me to use `#include <cmath>`. I could easily do this if I could use `pow(x, y)` but I cannot. This question has got me stumped. I will post the code I have so far! Maybe I am just not understanding the question properly. Any help would be very much appreciated. Also I know that my current code does not make much sense, but I have been trying other things. Thanks again

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int integerPower(int base, int exponent)
{
    int answer = base * exponent;
    return answer;
}


int main()
{
    cout << integerPower(3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Hint; Powering a number is repeated multiplication. 2. Hint: C++ provides the `for()` loop construct.

Comment: In your example, you say that `integerPower(3, 4) == 3 * 3 * 3 *3`. Your code does `3 * 4`. Which is different...

Comment: Yes which is why I am trying to figure out how to go about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int integerPower(int base, int exponent)
{
    int answer = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<exponent; ++i)
        answer *= base;
    return answer;
}


int main()
{
    cout << integerPower(3, 4);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. If you don't mind I want to try to pick your brain. So what you are doing is your setting an int = to 1. Then you are making a for loop and setting another int (i) = to 0. and if i is less than the number I put for my exponent, iterate by 1. Then set answer *= base. Do I have the right idea?

Comment: We have base as 3 and exponent as 4. answer is 1 initially. for loop starts. i is 0. answer = answer * base so it becomes 3. Then i becomes 1 and now again answer is multiplied with base so it becomes 9. Then 27 and then 81 at this point i becomes 4 which is not less than exponent and for loop terminates.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Thank you very much for this. Learning C++ code is really fun by the way. I was really stuck on this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a touch of recursion in this,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int integerPower(int base, int exponent)
{
    if (exponent == 0) return 1; //Anything raised to power zero is one.
    else return base * integerPower(base,exponent-1);
}


int main()
{
    cout << integerPower(3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```